# Icons for each file type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In my MVC application, user can upload various type of files (pdf, jpg, txt etc) and I want to show icon specific to each type, currently I am using one icon (pdf) for the purpose, I want, that based on the file type, associated icon should be displayed. Please guide me what kind of approach I can use for this purpose

```
<td>
@if (item.CalibratedBy != null){
<a href = @Url.Action("ViewCertificate", new { fileName = item.CalibrationCert }) > 
<img src = "@Url.Content("~/Content/Icons/pdf.jpg")"  alt = "attachment" /> </a>
}
</td>
```

Comment: Are you including the different types for some files for the same type of icon?  Like .doc, .docx, etc, for documents?  Just curious because I had to provide such a service and it was a headache.  In the end, I had a table in the DB that was linked to an icons table and displayed the appropriate icon based on the type.

Comment: I am also thinking about the same approach you mentioned. I think its a easier way. However, can u share your code?

Comment: I will try to get my example up soon as I can.  I think for the most part, what I did was look at the extension and then try to match it up in the table that held my extensions.  From there, I had an foreign key field to another table that held my icons.  I would return my foreign key and then match the image based off the key returned (switch statement I think).  I'll look into it further (my code was from an old project and I don't have it with me at the moment, sorry).

Comment: Thanks, I will wait for code :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Expose the extension type needed as a property on `item` (presumably being passed in through the Model)
2. Create an `HtmlHelper` extension method that will take in `item.FileType` and return the path to the appropriate icon file to be used. Call this in your `<img>` tag.